# »function windowResized()« on smartphones

Tags: javascript, mobile, p5.js, smartphone, paperjs

I work with p5.js. To adjust sketches for different window sizes this helps:

```
function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

**But:** It seems that it does not work on smartphones. I have a new iPhone with Google Chrome installed. If I hold my phone vertical, the Sketches run, if I tilt then my phone horizontal, the Sketch area is much smaller.

Is there a way to solve this? I have this problem also with paper.js.

Love

Comment: I don't know if P5.js exposes a wrapper for phone rotation, but if not, you could google something like "JavaScript phone rotate event" for a ton of resources. Remember that P5.js is JavaScript, so anything that works in JavaScript will work in P5.js.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I can't find something matching. Or is there the possiblity to reload the website if the orientation is changing?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure that's possible. Again I'd recommend googling- something like "JavaScript refresh page" will return a ton of results.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I found that: »if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() { location.reload(); }, false);
}« and it works. Thank you. Have a nice day and don't drink too much beer! :)

Comment: Ha, glad you got it figured out. Feel free to post what you found as an answer so that other people with similar problems in the future can learn from your research.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) { window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() { location.reload(); }, false); }
```